# Onde implementar Facade no MVC?

Tags: c#, mvc

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em C# usando MVC, mas o professor quer que todos os projetos dos alunos tenham Facade, a dúvida é a seguinte !

Onde eu implemento a Facade, Model, View ou Controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O objetivo principal do  `Facade`  é mediar a interação entre uma `view` e um `model`, ou em alguns casos apenas um `model`. No seu caso você implementa no `controller`.